# Is this reversed P-MOS next to the battery for some other purpose?

Tags: mosfet, batteries, fet, reverse-polarity

I was handed a schematic with this P-FET next to the battery. My experience tells me that this would not provide any reverse polarity protection (which at a glance it what I thought it was for), but I can't figure out if the original designer had another purpose for it.

Does anyone know if it might be used for another purpose?

[image]

Comment: I would guess it is a mistake where the PMOS was installed the wrong way because the author did not understand how it is supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks, that was my feeling too, but wanted to check it wasn't done intentionally for reasons I didn't understand!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a reverse polarity protection circuit. Keep in mind that if the battery is the supply, the drain and source of the PFET should be transposed as shown in the following [circuit](https://hackaday.com/2011/12/06/reverse-voltage-protection-with-a-p-fet/). To turn on the PFET, the gate must be pulled low. If the voltage is reverse applied, then Vgs is not pulled low and the PFET remains off. The reason that the PFET has to be connected this way to to prevent its bypass diode conducting if the voltage is reverse applied.

[image]

Comment: PMOS  in OP's circuit is facing the wrong way for this. It can't be a charger where the battery is a load.